# Java Altering a GUI from a different class

Tags: java, class, actionlistener

So my program has multiple classes and after one of them has run, it'd like it so it appends the text area in the main class GUI with a 'finished' message

```
ta.append("Search Complete\n");
```

and this is the code that needs to complete

```
statCl.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                ta.append("Searching...\n");
                task.execute();
            } catch (Exception IOE) {}
        }
});
```

So it is in the class where `task` where actual code runs.

Any advice or help would be amazing, thanks.

Comment: Oh and I've tried making the original declaration of 'ta' public and thats not working. Says it can't have the word public in the declaration

Comment: is task.execute() asynchronous ?

Comment: I have absolutely NO idea whether it is or not lol Not exactly the worlds greatest programmer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the task.execute() method doesn't start launch an operation in another thread, then the GUI will be freezed, and nothing will apear in the text area until the operation is finished. So you might just have

```
ta.append("Searching...\n");
task.execute();
ta.append("Finished");
```

If the operation is launched in a new thread, then this thread should append in the text area, but it should make sure this append is done in the event dispatch thread (EDT). Your code could thus look like this :

```
public class Task {
    private JTextArea ta;
    public Task(JTextArea ta) {
        this.ta = ta;
    }

    public void execute() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            // perform the long operation
            // at the end, update the text area, in the EDT
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ta.append("finished");
                }
            });
        }
        t.start();
    }
}
```

You might also look at [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), which is designed just for that (and other things like progress update). There is a code example in its class javadoc which does just what you're trying to do.

Comment: The Task class does use SwingWorker cause someone on here recommended it to me before so I've got that part. I'll try implementing this part now, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be performing long-running task on EDT (event dispatching thread):
http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Swing does all it's work on EDT, so you should not block EDT, e.g. run intensive tasks on it. Note: all event handlers are executed on EDT.

So there are two challenges:

1. Run intensive tasks in a background thread.
2. Update GUI, which must be done on EDT.

Use [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to solve this two issues.